# Looking for an efficient way to convert a string to logging's log level

Tags: python

I am using logger module. In my code have something like this:

`logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

I like to set the log level in my application using a command line argument, so the I'll have a string contains one of the logging's log level define inside the module:

```
CRITICAL = 50
FATAL = CRITICAL
ERROR = 40
WARNING = 30
WARN = WARNING
INFO = 20
DEBUG = 10
NOTSET = 0
```

I don't want ask people give me the log level number. I like them give a string through my application's command line.

I know that I can use Python's match-case to do this. Coming from C# background and used to C#'s Enums, I really hope I don't have to use Python's match-case to do this.

Is there a better, more concise way to convert a string to above log levels?

Comment: Efficient or short?   use a map, then look up the map to get the log level.  Default to something sensible if not found.   Hint here: https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-list-of-string-into-list-of-integers-python/

Comment: Efficient is usually short, although that is very subjectible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more clear if I create a dictionary?

Comment: BTW, Thanks for help,map is much better than match-case.

Comment: @hookenz, since you promptly responded, did you want to create an answer so you get the credit for it?

Comment: Sorry not certain.  I'm not a python programmer but it does seem that you can map strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a dictionary and have the values mapped to different log level string name.

Try this :

```
log_level = {
    "CRITICAL": 50,
    "FATAL": 'CRITICAL',
    "ERROR": 40,
    "WARNING": 30,
    "WARN": 'WARNING',
    "INFO": 20,
    "DEBUG": 10,
    "NOTSET": 0
}
```

Comment: Can't have "FATAL": 'CRITICAL',

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please explain a little ?

Comment: The dictionary must return numbers only.

Comment: So in that case you will have to specify a number for `FATAL'.  The same goes for `WARN`.